# Angular 2: Property 'suscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, rest, web-services, http, typescript

Error above is what I get (referring to the second call of the subscribe method in the post request. Pretty straight-forward) in the command line after "compiling", I am subscribing to an observable to get a response to an http request. No services (at least that I created) are being imported in some other folder, supposedly everything needed for the post method to work. Also, I have set up mock APIs, which postman is successfully able to make get and post requests to/from.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-http',
    templateUrl: 'simple-http.component.html'
})

export class SimpleHttpComponent implements OnInit{
    data: Object;


    loading: boolean;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
    }



    ngOnInit() {

    }

    getUser(): Object {
        this.loading = true;
        this.http.get('http://demo1495487.mockable.io/cort')
            .subscribe((res: Response) => {
                this.data = res.json();
                this.loading = false;
                console.log(this.data);
            });
            return this.data;
    }

    addUser(): void {
      this.loading = true;
      this.http.post('http://greenmachine.mockable.io/cortfield',
      JSON.stringify({
        body: 'bar',
        title: 'foo',
        userId: 1
      }))
      .suscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.data = res.json();
        console.log(this.data);
        this.loading = false;
      });
    }





}
```

Comment: Not suscribe it's subscribe

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your code I can understand that you are spelled wrongly on your code.

change your code from

```
 .suscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.data = res.json();
        console.log(this.data);
        this.loading = false;
      });
```

to

```
.subscribe((res: Response) => {
            this.data = res.json();
            console.log(this.data);
            this.loading = false;
          });
```

Try to map in to JSON before you subscribe it.

```
  this.http.post('http://greenmachine.mockable.io/cortfield',
        JSON.stringify({
          body: 'bar',
          title: 'foo',
          userId: 1
        })).map((response: Response) => {
            return <any>response.json();
        }).subscribe((response: any) => {

            this.data = response;
            console.log(this.data);
            this.loading = false;
        });
```

or

```
this.http.post('http://greenmachine.mockable.io/cortfield',
            JSON.stringify({
              body: 'bar',
              title: 'foo',
              userId: 1
            })).subscribe(result => this.data=result.json());
```

Comment: That error has been corrected, still getting the same error.

Comment: @PaulHubert I have updated my answer..Could you please try that

Comment: @PaulHubert I think the second implementation is same as like your implementation but a small change. Please try that